# Erro no Ubuntu: NO_PUBKEY 8BAF9A6F

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Meu Ubuntu começou a dar o seguinte erro:

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key 
is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8BAF9A6F

Quem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você deveria fazer essa pergunta no site apropriado: http://askubuntu.com/. Aqui é para assuntos relacionados a programação. Veja o [**tour**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Veja as respostas dessa pergunta: http://askubuntu.com/q/13065/207566. Talvez ajude no teu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute no terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8BAF9A6F
```

e depois:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Vai resolver!